# Корица и коричневый

Tags: этимология

Интересно, а что от чего произошло: слово "корица" от слова "коричневый" или наоборот?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Корица* - это пряность, которая является по сути высушенной *корой* дерева. Дерево, кстати, тоже называется *корицей* (наверное, по названию пряности) или *коричником* настоящим, являющимся представителем *коричных* лавров (прошу обратить внимание, что не "*коричневых*"). Так что получается, что *коричневый* - это именно "цвета как у корицы", а *коричный* - "относящийся к корице"

Answer (score 3):

"Коричневый" произошло от слова "корица" (уменьшительное от "кора"). Коричневый - буквально цвета корицы. Источник - словарь Фасмера.